# Getting error with MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate EXE_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8)

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, exc-bad-access, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to make mail composer as a helper class. It shows window when called from `viewcontroller` class `viewDidLoad` method. But when I press cancel and then Delete Draft. The app is crashing. After crashing its going to main file and showing following error message.

```
EXE_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x8).
```

I have tried all the possible things, but still didn't get any solution.

Any advice will be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance.

Below are the code.

ViewController.m :-

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Allocating mailing object.
    EmailManagerDelegate *MailOperation=[[EmailManagerDelegate alloc] init]; 

    //Email Subject
    MailOperation.emailTitle=@"just trying mail composer";
    //Email content.
    MailOperation.messageBody=@"hallo world";
    //To address
    MailOperation.toRecipent=[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"abc@gmail.com"];

    //Setting the name of the File with Format in nstring.
    MailOperation.FileNameWithFormat=@"Demo.txt";

    //Passing the UIViewCOntroller for opeing the mailclient and closing it.
    MailOperation.ViewVontroller=self;

    [MailOperation emailMultiAttachAndSendLog:nil fileName: nil];

}
```

EmailManagerDelegate.h :-

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@interface OSMEmailManagerDelegate : NSObject <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

@property (readwrite) NSString* FileNameWithFormat;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController* ViewVontroller;
//@property (nonatomic) UIViewController* ViewVontroller;
@property (nonatomic,strong) MFMailComposeViewController *mc;
@property (readwrite)NSString* emailTitle;
@property (readwrite)NSString* messageBody;
@property (readwrite)NSArray* toRecipent;

-(void)emailMultiAttachAndSendLog:(NSString*)documentsDirectory fileName:(NSString*)fileWithFormat;
```

EmailManagerDelegate.m :-

```
 #import "OSMEmailManagerDelegate.h"

    @implementation OSMEmailManagerDelegate

    @synthesize mc,ViewVontroller;

    -(void)emailMultiAttachAndSendLog:(NSString*)documentsDirectory  fileName:(NSString*)fileWithFormat{


        if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
            // The device can send email.
        {

         //Creating a  mail composer
         mc=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        [mc setMailComposeDelegate:self];
        [mc setSubject:_emailTitle];
        [mc setMessageBody:_messageBody isHTML:NO];
        [mc setToRecipients:_toRecipent];
        [mc setModalPresentationStyle: UIModalPresentationFormSheet];

        NSData *fileData;
        NSString *mimeType;
        NSString *filesName;
        if (documentsDirectory && fileWithFormat) {
            //Files section
            NSArray *filePart=[fileWithFormat componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
            filesName=[filePart objectAtIndex:0];
            NSString *fileExtention=[filePart objectAtIndex:1];

            //Getting and creating path of the zip file.
            NSString *fileArchivePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, fileWithFormat];

            //Geting the resource file and path
            fileData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fileArchivePath];

            //Determining the MIME type.
            mimeType=[self getMIMEType:fileExtention];

            //Add attachment
            [mc addAttachmentData:fileData mimeType:mimeType fileName:filesName];
         }

            //Present mail view controller on screen.
            [ViewVontroller presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:nil];

        }
        else
            // The device can not send email.
        {
            UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Device not configured to send mail." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            [alert show];
        }

    }

    //Get the type of MIME with file extention.
    -(NSString *)getMIMEType:fileExtention{
        NSString *mimeType=@"";
        if ([fileExtention isEqualToString:@"csv"]) {
            mimeType=@"text/csv";
        }
        else if ([fileExtention isEqualToString:@"jpg"]) {
            mimeType = @"image/jpeg";
        } else if ([fileExtention isEqualToString:@"png"]) {
            mimeType = @"image/png";
        } else if ([fileExtention isEqualToString:@"doc"]) {
            mimeType = @"application/msword";
        } else if ([fileExtention isEqualToString:@"ppt"]) {
            mimeType = @"application/vnd.ms-powerpoint";
        } else if ([fileExtention isEqualToString:@"html"]) {
            mimeType = @"text/html";
        } else if ([fileExtention isEqualToString:@"pdf"]) {
            mimeType = @"application/pdf";
        } else if ([fileExtention isEqualToString:@"json"]) {
            mimeType = @"text/json";
        } else if ([fileExtention isEqualToString:@"zip"]) {
            mimeType = @"application/zip";
        }
        return mimeType;
    }


    -(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error{
        NSString *status;
        switch(result){
            case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
                status=@"Mail cancelled";
                break;
            case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
                status=@"Mail saved";
                break;
            case MFMailComposeResultSent:
                status=@"Mail sent";
                break;
            case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
                status=@"Mail sent failure : %@",[error localizedDescription];
                break;
            default:
                break;

        }
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:status delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];

        //Close mail interface.
        [ViewVontroller dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    }
```

Comment: Add an exception breakpoint to see where the crash is occuring

Comment: I have tried and after cancel button crashing and going directly to the main file. I even tried Add Exception Breakpoint.

Comment: Very confused,how this is not working ? Need to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have the mailComposeController dismiss itself. You have to have the UIViewController that presents it to dismiss it.

You need to move the delegation method to your UIViewController...

Here's my summerised answer to a re-write of your code:

```
@interface UIViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

//Allocating mailing object.
MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init]; 

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
        // The device can send email.

    mc=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [mc setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    [mc setSubject:@"hello world"];
    [mc setMessageBody:@"hello world" isHTML:NO];
    [mc setToRecipients:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"abc@gmail.com"]];
    [mc setModalPresentationStyle: UIModalPresentationFormSheet];

    // This is the data you could handle in your custom class... I am   leaving this code as is, fix it in the way your logic works. 
    [MailOperation emailMultiAttachAndSendLog:nil fileName: nil];

            //Present mail view controller on screen.
        [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:nil];

     } else {
           // The device can not send email.
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"Device not configured to send mail." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
     }
}

    -(void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error{
    NSString *status;
    switch(result){
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            status=@"Mail cancelled";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            status=@"Mail saved";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            status=@"Mail sent";
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            status=@"Mail sent failure : %@",[error localizedDescription];
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:status delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

    //Close mail interface.
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

}
```

EmailManagerDelegate.h :- (Don't call it Delegate... it's not what a delegate it... refactor it and remove the word delegate)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@interface OSMEmailManagerDelegate : NSObject 

@property (readwrite) NSString* FileNameWithFormat;
// @property (nonatomic, strong) UIViewController* ViewVontroller;
//@property (nonatomic) UIViewController* ViewVontroller;
//@property (nonatomic,strong) MFMailComposeViewController *mc;
//@property (readwrite)NSString* emailTitle;
//@property (readwrite)NSString* messageBody;
//@property (readwrite)NSArray* toRecipent;

//-(void)emailMultiAttachAndSendLog:(NSString*)documentsDirectory fileName:(NSString*)fileWithFormat;
```

EmailManagerDelegate.m :- (Again, highly suggested to remove the 'delegate' part)

```
 #import "OSMEmailManagerDelegate.h"

@implementation OSMEmailManagerDelegate

//Get the type of MIME with file extention.
-(NSString *)getMIMEType:fileExtention{
    NSString *mimeType=@"";
    if ([fileExtention isEqualToString:@"csv"]) {
        mimeType=@"text/csv";
    }
    else if ([fileExtention isEqualToString:@"jpg"]) {
        mimeType = @"image/jpeg";
    } else if ([fileExtention isEqualToString:@"png"]) {
        mimeType = @"image/png";
    } else if ([fileExtention isEqualToString:@"doc"]) {
        mimeType = @"application/msword";
    } else if ([fileExtention isEqualToString:@"ppt"]) {
        mimeType = @"application/vnd.ms-powerpoint";
    } else if ([fileExtention isEqualToString:@"html"]) {
        mimeType = @"text/html";
    } else if ([fileExtention isEqualToString:@"pdf"]) {
        mimeType = @"application/pdf";
    } else if ([fileExtention isEqualToString:@"json"]) {
        mimeType = @"text/json";
    } else if ([fileExtention isEqualToString:@"zip"]) {
        mimeType = @"application/zip";
    }
    return mimeType;
}
```

Comment: The problem is mailComposeController didFinishWithResult is not firing. its not being called at all.

Comment: Same way I implemented in another project and its working fine.I am not able to understand why its failing here.And If you see the code I am passing the UIViewController from the ViewController.h page.

Comment: Basically, I would rewrite the whole code frankly. 
If you want to have an NSObject class to handle the data, ok, but the stuff you're doing here mostly need to be in the UIViewController.

Comment: Yes, agreed, but I am passing the UIVewController object shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: The delegation methods should be in the UIViewcontroller who is presenting the mailComposeController. Beyond that you could handle data in a model class.

Comment: By the way, the property 'ViewController' should be 'viewController'. Don't use upperclass letter in the beggining of a variable.

Comment: And have it weak, otherwise you're creating a retention cycle.

Comment: No its not working the way you suggested. I am missing something. If possible can you modify the code?

Comment: Yeah, give me a minute.

Comment: I've posted a re-edit. Obviously, you will need to customize your logic in the method I've left out.

Comment: I am sorry for the inconvenience, but I want to make a helped class where I will send only some amount of data( Check in viewController.m page).And it should work normally. And also I can make it work on viewController.m page without helper class.But i want a helper class. And also previously i thought to make it as delegate but I changed the plan so project name stayed same.

Comment: Move the code you have in the 'delegate' class in to the UIView controller just before you displaying the mailController.

Comment: Create an instance of that class, and do all the data stuff there, just pass to this method the return: 
            [mc addAttachmentData:fileData mimeType:mimeType fileName:filesName];

Comment: Is it not possible to make it work with data which I am passing in the ViewController.m section?

Comment: If you want, you could move that methods as well. Your app won't be rejected if you do that.. but It's better to separate MVC - model-view-controller for design patters purposes.

Answer (score 0):

The following line causes the exception.

```
EmailManagerDelegate *MailOperation=[[EmailManagerDelegate alloc] init];
```

Notice that `MailOperation` is a local variable, which only lives in `viewDidLoad`, so when you click the send button, it no longer exists.

Changing it to a global variable inside `ViewController` should work.